# Relativistic Projective Geometry

Tags: projective-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, general-relativity

If we assume that space-time has an extra two dimensions so that there is more symmetry between space (with 3) and time (now with 3). What would the corresponding cross ratio equation look like if we approached the problem using hyperbolic and projective geometry?

Comment: It might help if you could quote the cross ratio equation in some other setup (with one-dimensional time?) for comparison.

Comment: I don't understand this topics, but I think this post it's too short and should contain more explanations, exemplification of what you mean by "cross ratio equation", and also if space time has more dimensions, that would make a different universe, you better suggest how that would behave, one cannot guess how it would be, instead one has to define it, or at least leave less variability and freedom than what you are saying.